# PHP Extract only simple products with price below 10 from a csv file

Tags: php

I am trying to get some specific data from a csv file. Here is the file:
[image]

Until now I read the data row by row and get printed all of the data. I am trying to read it column by column and get only simple product with price below 10. Then I need to save the result in a new csv. file. Here is my code:

```
<?php


$row = 1;
$mycsvfile = array(); //define the main array.
if (($handle = fopen("php-files-task.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
foreach ($handle as $data) {
fputcsv($fp, $data);
}
}
?>
```

The first argument for fputcsv is wrong so I think it must be an array ot something similar to be able to put the result in a new file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me.

```
$row = 1;
$mycsvfile = array(); //define the main array.
$new_array = array();
if (($handle = fopen("php-files-task.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    if($data['product_t'] == 'simple' && $data['price'] < 10){
        $new_array = array_push($new_array, $data);
    }
}
fclose($handle);
$fp = ['sku', 'product_t', 'name', 'price'];
foreach ($new_array as $key => $value) {
    fputcsv($fp, $value);
}
```

Comment: On my side I receive a notice:  Undefined index: product_type on line 10!

Comment: actually the column name is 'product_type' but still I receive undefined index for it!